# Storing a UNC in JSON and loading into a dict

Tags: python, json

I have a situation where a JSON configuration document, editable by users, needs to be loaded into a dictionary in my application.

One specific scenario causing problems is a windows UNC path, such as:

```
\\server\share\file_path
```

So, valid JSON for this would intuitively be:

```
{"foo" : "\\\server\\share\\file_path"}
```

however this is invalid.

I'm going in circles with this.  Here are some trials:

```
# starting with a json string
>>> x = '{"foo" : "\\\server\\share\\file_path"}'
>>> json.loads(x)
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 18 (char 18)

# that didn't work, let's try to reverse engineer a dict that's correct
>>> d = {"foo":"\\server\share\file_path"}
>>> d["foo"]
'\\server\\share\x0cile_path'

# good grief, where'd my "f" go?
```

SUMMARY

- How do I create a properly formatted JSON document that includes **\\server\share\file_path**?
- How to I load that string into a dictionary that will return the exact value?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the escape sequences supported by the string literal.  Using [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), this becomes clearer:

```
>>> d = {"foo":"\\server\share\file_path"}
>>> d
{'foo': '\\server\\share\x0cile_path'}
>>> d = {"foo": r"\\server\share\file_path"}
>>> d
{'foo': '\\\\server\\share\\file_path'}
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"foo": "\\\\\\\\server\\\\share\\\\file_path"}'
>>> with open('out.json', 'w') as f: f.write(json.dumps(d))
... 
>>> 
$ cat out.json 
{"foo": "\\\\server\\share\\file_path"}
```

Without raw strings, you must "escape all the things!"

```
>>> d = {"foo":"\\server\share\file_path"}
>>> d
{'foo': '\\server\\share\x0cile_path'}
>>> d = {"foo":"\\\\server\\share\\file_path"}
>>> d
{'foo': '\\\\server\\share\\file_path'}
>>> print d['foo']
\\server\share\file_path
```